# "see more detail" at the bottom of a div / prevent text from leaving bottom of div

Tags: html, css

I have this news feed that I'm making for my school website and I want it to model this news feed: [Harvard Website](http://www.harvard.edu) Similar to that of Pinterest I believe.

I am using isotope to fill the grids so that I can sort by type and also minimize the 2d packing.  [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co)

My end goal is to have the size of the div be a certain percentage of the text height so that there is some variation in heights and then proceed in cutting off the rest of the text and adding a link to the full news article.

Questions:
Is there an easy way to find how long the contents of a div are?
Is there an easy way to see if that content is running over ending of the div and if so where does it start running over?

Comment: Sounds to me like you need to use JavaScript.

Comment: Thats what I think too.  Don't know jquery but might be something in that library idk.

Comment: How are you going to determine how much text goes in the div ? First sentence? X number of words/letters?

Comment: Several sentences will go in a div and if it is over a certain number of letters (including paragraph enters) a certain percentage of the article will be displayed (min content=x-number-words    max content=percent).  The divs change widths but the content will not.  Maybe what I need to do is read in the data from files and then only read a certain number of words??  Then when i click the link it reads the full article from file?

Comment: How will you determine the width of the div? Also use @ kittycat3141 (without the space) in your comment so I know when you respond.

Comment: I have my columns in thirds so i just use width:33% (30% given my margins) @kittycat3141

Comment: Would it be best to surround it with another div and use "overflow-y:hidden"